# One query in esper is getting executed more than once on one event

Tags: esper

I have the following query:

```
select f_user_id from completeEvent(class in(1,2)) where Utils.check(2345,f_user_id) = true.
```

under utils class 'check' is a static method.

what we have observed here is :

when i do `sender.sendEvent(completeEvent);`
check method is getting called around 240 times.

but it should have called only once, as i am sending only one completeEvent and i have registered this Query only once into the system.

Can anyone please tell what could be the reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to attach the code to the post. The code is likely doing something wrong like creating the EPL statement multiple times.

Comment: Its a pretty big project so cannot put whole code here .we have verified none of the Query is registered for more than once.

Comment: I'd try to reproduce it in a small piece of code outside of your big project. If there is something wrong with your big project its hard to help you here.